# What kind of ID to use and how to store it in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, uniqueidentifier

I am currently working on a new web based project with various types of entities. This service will be accessible through an REST API, and I'm thinking about endpoints like:

`api.example.com/users/{user_id}`

For this, I think that an auto-incremental ID for users will be a bad approach, since anybody can hit:
`api.example.com/users/1`, and then `api.example.com/users/2`, `api.example.com/users/3`, and so on.

Now, I'm thinking to use UUID, but I don't know if it's a good idea, because it's a `VARCHAR(36)`. For these reason, I do something like this when I generate the user ID on the **INSERT** query (I'm using **MySQL**):

`unhex(replace(uuid(),'-',''))`

With this, I'm casting the UUID to binary. And I'm storing an `BINARY(16)` on the database instead.

And when I want to retrieve info from database, I can use something like that:

`SELECT hex(id), name FROM user;`

and

`SELECT hex(id), name FROM user WHERE hex(id) = '36c5f55620ef11e7b94d6c626d968e15';`

So, I'm working with Hexadecimal form, but storing it in binary form.
It is this a good approach?

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with using a plain auto increment column for the user ID.  You need to have session management setup to prevent an unauthorized attempt to access a REST endpoint.  Switching to a UUID does little in the way of security.

Answer (score 0):

*Almost* there...

Indexes are your performance friend.  Presumably `id` is indexed, then

```
WHERE id = function('...')
```

uses the index and goes straight to the row, but

```
WHERE function(id) = '...'
```

cannot use the index; instead, it scans all the rows, checking each one.  For a large table, this is sloooow.

So...

Use this to store it:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (uuid, ...)
    VALUES
    (UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '')), ...);
```

And this to test for it:

```
SELECT ... WHERE
    uuid = UNHEX(REPLACE('786f3c2a-21f6-11e7-9392-80fa5b3669ce', '-', ''));
```

If you choose to send (via REST) the 32 characters without the dashes, you can figure that minor variation.

Since that gets tedious, build a pair of Stored Functions.  Oh, I have one for you; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid .
That also discusses why UUIDs are inefficient for huge tables, and a possible way around it.